# Does Filepicker support uploading videos from Instagram account?

Tags: filepicker.io

I have been trying to get instagram service working for uploading video on filepicker.io. It shows an error - 'incorrect mimetype' if uploader is limited to mkv. If we remove the extension setting, then the video shows up as image in the selection window.

Does Filepicker.io support uploading videos from your Instagram account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the Ink filepicker support response:

> We don't do video import from facebook, but we do from many other services (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.)

I could not get video import from instagram to work as well so I assume it is not supported.